# Test cases DB design

Tags: mysql, database

I`m working on web site which will test some applications or web sites with some test cases. And I dont know how to store this test cases which will be created by user. Is it okay to create separate table for each user? Or store all data in one table? So i have idea to create 3 new tables for each user (test_cases_x (will store all test cases which user has created), test_cases_history_x (will store references to all test cases which have been executed), test_cases_exe_x(will store all references to all test cases which are executing in this moment))

Comment: x is a id of current user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it okay to create separate table for each user?

No, this is defeating the whole idea of a relational database.  You want the three tables but to link them by user id.

its hard without knowing all the information - however it usually better 99% of the time not to create specific tables on a per user basis but use the database to perform linkage (relationships).

If you're concerned your table will grow really large you can look at partition / sharding / archiving data to reduce it (please don't look there until you need to as premature optimization can actually make it perform slower)

Comment: no i do not want to create new table for each user i will store users in one table. but i want create for each users 3 tables where they gonna store their test cases

Comment: so is it okay? or its better to store all test cases in one table?